# spring.view.prefix: not being applied to simple view name in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-boot

First off, my POM is correct and I understand the caveats with using JSP with Boot!  The following properties

```
    @Value("${spring.view.prefix:}")
    private String prefix = "";

    @Value("${spring.view.suffix:}")
    private String suffix = "";
```

are not being injected into WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter and I cannot determine why.  Has anyone else had this problem?  I'm using

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems they are changing the property names with Spring Boot 1.3. Now those would be `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix`, as per the [reference material](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers).

Comment: That was part of the problem.  The other bit was a trailing space following /WEB-INF/jsp/ .  Between the key names changing and not trimming spaces from property values, I'm not sure 1.3 is much of an improvement :(